# My fruit punch Gatorade has a new warning label saying that it is genetically engineered

Tags: cancer, food-safety

I drink fruit punch Gatorade pretty often - once to three times a week, I'd say.

Tonight, my bottle has a new warning label on it, written in boldface:

> **Partially produced with genetic engineering.**

What does this mean?  Is there now a documented food safety risk for Gatorade, and that perhaps I should avoid drinking it?

I am wondering if the warning label means that Gatorade can cause cancers.

Not asking for medical advice - just want to understand whether genetically engineered foods are a health risk at all.

Thanks

Comment: The title of your question has almost nothing whatsoever to do with what your question actually is. Could you edit it, please? If you don't, I will.

Comment: @CareyGregory I have edited now - would you like to post an answer? 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[FDA guidelines for GenMod Foods](https://www.fda.gov/food/ingredientspackaginglabeling/geplants/default.htm)

> FDA regulates the safety of food for humans and animals, including foods produced from genetically engineered (GE) plants. Foods from GE plants must meet the same food safety requirements as foods derived from traditionally bred plants. Read more at Consumer Info About Food From Genetically Engineered Plants.

In the USA at least, the FDA regulates the general health risks of all foods as they are *currently* understood before allowing a company to sell those foods. If you are looking for an official source to tell you that GenMod'd food is as safe to consume as the unmodified version, this would be one. On the other hand, research concerning GenMod is still being conducted, and the FDA is not always up to date, so YMMV.

Comment: I have no current citation to back it up, but I would think that dyes in foods/drinks would be more likely to cause cancer than the foods/drinks themselves, based on other countries banning certain dyes for being carcinogenic (I'm looking at you Canada).